# Server 2008: Switch from Terminal Services Mode to Remote Administration

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, terminal-services, remote-administration

It seems that two of our Server 2008 machines were configured to be Remote Desktop Hosts with Terminal Services. We do not have a TS license for this, and needed these setup to be managed in the standard Remote Admin mode (2 RDP users only.)

Is there a way to switch this back, without temporarily removing the ability to remote into the servers? We do not have local access.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone ever needs to know - there is no way to "switch back" - you will have to entirely remove the Remote Desktop Hosts role from the server in order to place it back into the Remote Administration mode. This requires a reboot, so plan accordingly.